# Tensorflow seq2seq weight sharing

Tags: sequence, tensorflow

```
def rnn_seq2seq(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, cell, output_projection=None,feed_previous=False, dtype=tf.float32, scope=None):
  with tf.variable_scope(scope or "rnn_seq2seq"):
    _, enc_states = rnn.rnn(cell, encoder_inputs,dtype=dtype)


  def extract_argmax(prev, i):
    if output_projection is not None:
        prev = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(prev, output_projection[0], output_projection[1])
    return tf.to_float(tf.equal(prev,tf.reduce_max(prev,reduction_indices=[1],keep_dims=True)))

  loop_function = None
  if feed_previous:
    loop_function = extract_argmax

       #seq2seq.rnn_decoder is provided in tensorflow/models/rnn/seq2seq.py
  return seq2seq.rnn_decoder(decoder_inputs, enc_states[-1], cell, loop_function=loop_function)
```

I want to create two RNN models, one for training and another for testing. For that, I can call the function twice passing the feed_previous to True or False.

```
train_op,train_states = rnn_seq2seq(enc_inp,dec_inp,cell,output_projection=op,feed_previous=False)
test_op,_ = rnn_seq2seq(enc_inp,dec_inp,cell,output_projection=op,feed_previous=True)
```

But if I call the above function twice, wouldn't it create two different RNNs ? I am wondering if they would be able to share the weights.

Answer (score 1):

Both functions operate on the same default graph and so can reuse the variables, check out [variable scopes tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html) and see if your variables are created with `reuse=True` parameter

As a sanity check, try following snippet to list all variables in the default graph:

```
[v.name for v in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if v.op=='Variable']
```

Comment: I did have read the tutorial, but my understanding might have gaps.

I am passing two parameters to rnn_seq2seq which needs to be shared - "cell" and "output_projection". since I am passing the same thing, I think they will be shared. 

But I have doubts on the  seq2seq_decoder function provided in tensorflow.

Comment: I have narrowed down my doubt :
while creating GRUCell, rnn_decoder call 
"     output,new_state= cell(inp,states[-1])  " 
does it mean it has pointer to the states, or does it create a new state altogether copying only the value ?